# Curl is not sending certificate (certificate length 0) even though the certificate is attached as --cert and installed in Trusted Certificates

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate

I'm currently sending the client certificate along with the priv key to an URL:

```
curl -k --cacert ./transport.pem --key ./privkey.key --location --request POST 
"URL..." --header
 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials" --data-urlencode "scope=payments"
```

and am getting a 400 error "No required SSL certificate was sent". I've tried to capture the packets with WireShark and after the handshake, this is what I get:

```
Handshake Protocol: Certificate
    Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
    Length: 3
    Certificates Length: 0
```

From what I've read, this means that the certificate is not being sent, but I also read that this might mean that the server is rejecting the certificate. Could anyone give some pointers?
I've also installed the certificate to the Trusted Certificates. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a screenshot of Wireshark packets:
[image]

And here's a screenshot of the packet which should contain the cert:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can check the *makefile* of the curl.
I was using GUNTLS and I got the same issue. The client doesn't send out the certificate file with curl. But the OpenSSL has no issues.

```
openssl s_client -connect server_ip:443 -servername  server_name -key /etc/ssl/private/tls.key -cert /etc/ssl/certs/tls.crt -CAfile /etc/ssl/CA/tls-ca.crt
```

After I check the curl makefile, I found it is using guntls. Change it to ssl and all is ok.

```
-PACKAGECONFIG ??= "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "ipv6", "ipv6", "", d)} gnutls zlib"
+PACKAGECONFIG ??= "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_FEATURES", "ipv6", "ipv6", "", d)} ssl zlib"
```

Comment: Please reformat your answer with the code section.